# Sequence of List of Lists compared with another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to find out something like this

```
l1 = [1,[1,1]]
l2 = [2,[2,2]]
```

Since the sequence of list inside a lists is same for both l1 equals l2

```
l3 = [1,1,[1,1]]
l4 = [2,[2,2],2]
```

Here since the sequence of lists is not same l3 is not equal to l4

Edit:

l1 has list of length 2 at index 1, similar for l2 hence equal.

l3 has a list of length 2 at index = 2 but l4 has list of length 2 at index =1 which is not same as l3, hence unequal

Kindly point me in the right direction if something similar is already here.
If not then how to proceed on this.
I was thinking something on the lines of storing the length of inner lists along with their index in outer list and then compare for both. Since this would be very lengthy for large arrays I am seeking suggestions from you.
Thanks

PS: I am a beginner in Python

Comment: What is the question exactly? It's not clear from your post.

Comment: l1 is not equal to l2:

```
>>> [1,[1,1]] == [2,[2,2]]
False
```

Comment: To explain it a bit more : 
l1 has list of length 2 at index 1, similar for l2 
l3 has a list of length 2 at index = 2 but l4 has list of length 2 at index =1 which is not same as l3, hence unequal

Answer (score 1):

This program might do what you want:

```
def f(lst):
    return [type(x) for x in lst]

l1 = [1,[1,1]]
l2 = [2,[2,2]]
l3 = [1,1,[1,1]]
l4 = [2,[2,2],2]
l5 = [1,1,[1,1]]
l6 = [2,2,[2,2,2]]

assert f(l1) == f(l2)
assert f(l3) != f(l4)
assert f(l5) == f(l6)
```

EDIT:

This program works efficiently in space and time for very long lists. It is also works for lists of arbitrary depth.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def compare_shape(list1, list2):
    '''Compare the "shape" of two lists, ignoring the contents.'''

    # Use generators to save memory
    def shape(l):
        '''Flatten list to a series of tokens, [, ], or 0.'''
        if isinstance(l, list):
            yield '['
            for x in l:
                for y in shape(x):
                    yield y
            yield ']'
        else:
            yield 0

    # Use all() to save time.
    # Use izip to save memory
    # Use izip_longest to ensure correct answer if list1 is a prefix of list2
    return all(a == b
               for a,b in izip_longest(shape(list1),
                                       shape(list2), 
                                       fillvalue=object()))

l1 = [1,[1,1]]
l2 = [2,[2,2]]
l3 = [1,1,[1,1]]
l4 = [2,[2,2],2]
l5 = [1,1,[1,1]]
l6 = [2,2,[2,2,2]]

assert compare_shape(l1, l2)
assert not compare_shape(l3, l4)
assert not compare_shape(l5,l6)
```

Comment: Hey I don't think this would serve the purpose. In cases like `l3 = [1,1,[1,1]]
l4 = [2,2,[2,2,2]]` it would go wrong as both are lists at index = 2 but not of same length

Comment: You didn't describe that case in your question, so I had to guess what you meant. In that case, should the answer to "they are equal" or "they aren't equal"?  FYI, the first program in my answer would describe them as equal; the second would describe them as not equal.

Comment: Sorry for that, edited the same in the question now. Thanks for your answer. It works as I wanted. Will take some time to understand the solution though :P
Answer to the third case would be "not equal"